# mutilple data shows in line charts legends

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i had a issue, when the chart data is displaying the legends has to be shown theinformation of the charts.

But i need to show the multiple data columns for each each legends has to be displayed.

Can any one of you having this type component , please share to me. It is very urgent.

Please check the attached jpeg for reference.

Thanks,
Ravi

[link text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42GYD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create an [item renderer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_10.html) that contains or extends [`mx.charts.LegendItem`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/LegendItem.html).  It's a fairly easy class to use and configure.  I can't post the code for the method here for licensing reasons, but check out the private `addLegendItem` method on the [`mx.charts.Legend`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/Legend.html) to see how you can take the legendData from your chart and configure a LegendItem instance to use in your data grid.

Then you can use an [`mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html) or [`mx.controls.DataGrid`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html) to contain your LegendItem renderers and the rest of the data you want to display along with them.